# Filter a Pandas dataframe by a condition and a minimum value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to

```
  test_a test_b  metric_e
0     OK    NOK        12
1     OK     OK         7
2     OK    NOK         2
3     OK     OK        55
```

and I want to filter by one condition, meaning that `test_a == OK` and capture the minimum value on `metric_e`. I can accomplish that with two lines, copying a dataframe:

```
df_t = df[df.test_a == 'OK'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_t.iloc[df_t.metric_e.idxmin()].to_frame()

test_a | test_b | metric_e
OK     |  NOK   | 2
```

Is there a way to do it without having to use an intermediate dataframe?

Comment: Are you sure your output is right from your provided code?

Comment: If you want to capture the index, df2[(df2.test_a == 'OK') & (df2.metric_e == df2.metric_e.min())]

Comment: I need to get all values in the row in the dataframe that matches condition on test_a and is the minimum value in metric_e on this subset

Comment: @Vaishali - no,because need filter in already filtered data,so cannot be used here

Comment: It's similar but probably not a dupe, as the line that you mention will cause an error if the minimum value is filtered out by condition 1.

Comment: Well, not right now. I think I would be more concerned about memory use than runtime in this specific case, but my dataset is quite small right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion your solution is nice, also is possible join both rows of code together with double `[]` for return one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.loc[[df.loc[df.test_a == 'OK', 'metric_e'].idxmin()]]
print (df)
  test_a test_b  metric_e
2     OK    NOK         2
```

Answer (score 8):

Using [`nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html):

```
df[df['test_a']=='OK'].nsmallest(1, 'metric_e')
```

Output:

```
  test_a test_b  metric_e
2     OK    NOK         2
```

Comment: Most concise answer imo +1

Comment: If your question is about how to use it, you don't have to have the values sorted for using `nsmallest`. And if you're asking about how it's implemented in pandas, I just looked it up and it looks very interesting, they're apparently not sorting all the values but using some sort of selection algorithm. Their comment says `This method is equivalent to df.sort_values(columns, ascending=True).head(n), but more performant.` (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py, search for `nsmallest`)

Answer (score 1):

With the output from your code, you can try with:

```
df[df.metric_e==df.loc[df.test_a.eq('OK'),'metric_e'].min()].T

            2
test_a     OK
test_b    NOK
metric_e    2
```

If don't want transpose:

```
df[df.metric_e==df.loc[df.test_a.eq('OK'),'metric_e'].min()]

  test_a test_b  metric_e
2     OK    NOK         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice after `sort_values`

```
df.query("test_a=='OK'").sort_values('metric_e').iloc[[0]]# or head(1)
Out[658]: 
  test_a test_b  metric_e
2     OK    NOK         2
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using argmin ?

```
df.iloc[np.argmin(df.loc[df['test_a'] == 'OK','metric_e'])]
```