# Filter grouped pandas dataframe, keep all rows with minimum value in column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['SAM', 23, 1],
                   ['SAM', 23, 2],
                   ['SAM', 23, 1],
                   ['SAM', 23, 3],
                   ['BILL', 36, 1],
                   ['BILL', 36, 2],
                   ['BILL', 36, 3],
                   ['BILL', 36, 1],
                   ['JIMMY', 33, 4],
                   ['JIMMY', 33, 2],
                   ['JIMMY', 33, 2],
                   ['JIMMY', 33, 3],
                   ['CARTER', 25, 3],
                   ['CARTER', 25, 4],
                   ['CARTER', 25, 5],
                   ['CARTER', 25, 4],
                   ['GRACE', 27, 4],
                   ['GRACE', 27, 5],
                   ['GRACE', 27, 6],
                   ['TOMMY', 32, 7]])
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I need to keep in dataframe all rows with minimum values of 'C' column grouped by 'A' column and remain B the same.
There is almost same theme [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425010/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-condition-and-a-minimum-value-in-a-column)
but if i use

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A').C.idxmin()]
```

Only one minimum row remains, and i need all of them.
Expected result:

[image: image of expected result]

Comment: We can write code that does this, but you're asking to intentionally keep duplicate rows, which has almost no value. Can you show any legitimate use-case where we would ever want to do this?

Comment: Also, most solutions will not preserve the index, they'll overwrite it with default 0,1,2..., (but your original dataframe doesn't have a non-default index, so you won't notice). But if you do `df.index = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:20]` you'll see.

Comment: Yes. in real case (this is an example) i have a dataframe with 500k+ rows. and column B values are not the same, so rows are not duplicates. Im sorry for making you think they are the same in real life. just copy-pasted them.

Comment: I'm saying: if you want solutions that preserve the (non-default) index, edit your question to say so and provide a data example that has a (non-default) index. You've already accepted a solution that doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the minimum value of C per group and compare with `df['C']` and keep those `C` values that equal the minimum:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('min').eq(df['C'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
        A   B  C
0     SAM  23  1
1     SAM  23  1
2    BILL  36  1
3    BILL  36  1
4   JIMMY  33  2
5   JIMMY  33  2
6  CARTER  25  3
7   GRACE  27  4
8   TOMMY  32  7
```

Answer (score 0):

the idea here is to keep the data from your original df which matches the target of min 'C'. You can do that with merge:

```
pd.merge(df,df.groupby('A').min())
```